# I need to draw a point using OpenGL and GLUT, But I just get a blank black screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, point

I am trying to print a point using OpenGL and GLUT, but I just get blank screen when I run the following code. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

```
#include<GL/glut.h>

void display() {
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("example");
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

}
```

Comment: Maybe, the point (1 pixel) is just too small to be noticed. As you didn't setup any matrix I assume that they all are defaulted to identity (but I don't know for sure). Have you tried a triangle instead?

Comment: FYI: [Simple GLUT Example](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/simple.c). Btw. in the example, you find how to setup projection and model view matrix, and how to clear the frame buffer. (These are all things which are hard to guess for me, as I never wrote a GL program where I didn't setup matrices nor didn't clear the frame buffer initially. Clearing the frame buffer is the only thing which works always for me from the beginning in opposition to everything else which I've to fix most times before something becomes visible...) ;-)

Comment: I tried a circle which worked, but that was just copy and pasted from some website.

Comment: _I tried a circle which worked, but that was just copy and pasted from some website._ In this case, you have a working sample and yours and could compare what they did what you didn't. Sounds like a chance to try out if there can be something added to your MCVE to make it running. But I still recommend to try a triangle (a non-degenerated, of course) first to exclude that you just couldn't see the point (of 1 pixel)... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `glPointSize` before `glBegin`. Example:

```
void display() {
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glPointSize(10.0f);
  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}
```

If the point size is going to be the same each frame then you can just call `glPointSize` once on initialisation.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. What do I need to do to change the background color to white?

Comment: @Vijay `glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` would do that